# Not able to draw something on screen with OpenGL 2.1 and GLSL 1.2

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am trying to run this code which should render a simple triangle. It's launching correctly but I only see my grey background, no triangle.

Would you have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_FALSE);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE);

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// Let's use a grey background color, better for debugging
glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1);

// First triangle
float points[] = {
    -0.4f, 0.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, -0.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.8f, -0.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

GLuint vbo = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

const char* vertex_shader =
"#version 120\n"
"in vec4 vp;"
"void main () {"
"  gl_Position = vp;"
"}";

const char* fragment_shader =
"#version 120\n"
"void main () {"
"  gl_FragColor = vec4 (0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);"
"}";

GLuint vs = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource (vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
glCompileShader (vs);
GLuint fs = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource (fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
glCompileShader (fs);
GLuint shader_programme = glCreateProgram ();
glAttachShader (shader_programme, vs);
glAttachShader (shader_programme, fs);
glLinkProgram (shader_programme);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose (window) && !glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)) {
    // wipe the drawing surface clear
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram (shader_programme);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);

    // update other events like input handling
    glfwPollEvents ();
    // put the stuff we've been drawing onto the display
    glfwSwapBuffers (window);
}
/* End Actual Code */

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @genpfault: so I was wondering why we cannot write "Thanks in advance for the help!" in our questions?

Comment: It generally [doesn't impart any useful information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/150045).

Comment: Well even though I agree I believe that it shouldn't be a reason to not be polite between each other :)

Answer (score 3):

Honestly the error messages and numbers of OpenGl are sometimes not self explaining.

You still should use `glGetError`, `glGetShaderiv` with `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` and `glGetProgramiv` with `GL_LINK_STATUS` to detect if everything is ok.

If you use that you would have seen that the shader could not be compiled.

If the shader is not compiling you should use `glGetShaderInfoLog` to find out why.

The error OpenGL reporting is:

> ERROR: 0:2: Invalid qualifiers 'in' in global variable context

Normally that should be the information you provide with your question.

The problem with the `in` and `out` qualifiers is, that they are not part of the glsl `1.2`, there you use the deprecated `attribute` and `varying`.

As long as there is not real reason to use OpenGL < `3.2` (e.g. to maintain an old program)  you shouldn't learn the deprecated parts of the library.

Comment: Thank you @t.niese, I should definitely add all these checks and that's my next step to get a good working environment. The problem was indeed I was using 'in' instead of 'attribute', which should be used for older version of GLSL. The reason to stuck to OpenGL 2.1 is that the code has to run on some hardware that doesn't support higher versions of OpenGL, and the hardware cannot be updated at this point of time :)

Comment: @e-Jah Personally I place an `assert` after _every_  OpenGL command ;) The assert is inline and can be controlled with a global flag, so that it can fully or partially disabled in production code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was coming from the vertex shader program, for version 1.2 it should use attribute instead of in:

```
"in vec4 vp;"
```

Becomes

```
"attribute vec4 vp;"
```